# Building Couchbase caching application using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

Can anybody here direct me in the right direction to develop a caching application? Any links to the example are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty straight forward with Spring-boot.

1. Provide the couchbase-cluster configuration.
2. Define a bucket where every cache related data will be read/written into.
3. Spring expects a CacheManager bean. So define it something like this:

> ```
> @Bean
> public CacheManager cacheManager() {
> CacheBuilder cacheBuilder = 
> CacheBuilder.newInstance(bucket()).withExpiration(TTL);
> return new CouchbaseCacheManager(cacheBuilder, CACHE_NAME);
> }
> ```

4. Add annotation `@Configuration` and `@EnableCaching`

Now for the usage you can use annotations `@Cacheable`, `@CacheEvict`, `@CachePut` etc.
Simple usage:

```
@Cacheable(CACHE_NAME)
public String getCompanyName(String companyId){}
```

Hope it helps.